# when i add record, how can i insert value of foreign key in Sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, sequelize.js

I use sequelize ORM first time.

when i made models of table, i worked well so, i could see this in GUI database.

[image]

and this code is model of this table

```js
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class request extends Sequelize.Model {


    static associate(models) {
      models.request.belongsTo(models.model, {foreignKey: {name : "model_id", allowNull: true}})
      models.request.belongsTo(models.user, {foreignKey: {name : "user_id", allowNull: true}})
      models.request.hasOne(models.appraisal, {foreignKey: "request_id"})
    }
  };



  request.init({
    request_id : {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER(11),
      allowNull: false,
      unique : true,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    request_time : {
      type : Sequelize.DATE,
    },
    image_folder : {
      type : Sequelize.STRING(64)
    },
    image_file : {
      type : Sequelize.STRING(256)
    },
    result : {
      type : Sequelize.STRING(8)
    },
    result_value : {
      type : Sequelize.INTEGER(8)
    },
    product_image : {
      type : Sequelize.STRING(64)
    }
  }, {
    sequelize,
    timestamps: true,
    underscored: false,
    modelName: 'request',
    tableName: 'request',
    paranoid: false,
    charset: 'utf8',
    collate: 'utf8_general_ci',
    freezeTableName: true,
    tableName: "request"
  });
  return request;
};
```

but, when i add record like this,

```js
const request = new db.request();
  let data = {
    request_time : date,
    image_folder : path,
    image_file : filesName,
    result : resultBool,
    result_value : resultValue,
    product_image : "8.jpg",
    model_id : 1,
    user_id : 1
  }
  db.request.create(data);
```

it makes problem, Except for the foreign key, the values are successful inserted to columns, but foreign key doesn't get value. it always has null like this picture.

[image]

How can i add value of foreign key in sequelize? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you need to indicate `field` option in associations along with `name`:

```js
foreignKey: {name : "model_id", field : "model_id", allowNull: true}
```

If it still does not work then try to define `model_id` explicitly in the `request` model